# ANDs within OrConditionGroups

Tags: 8, database

I'm trying to use entityQuery in Drupal 8 to perform an "and" within an "or" group. A simplified version of what I'm trying to do is this: Query for all apples, oranges and bananas that are ripe. The code I'd like to be able to use would look like this code.

```php
$oQuery = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$oOrGroup = $oQuery->orConditionGroup();
$oOrGroup->condition('type',['apple','orange'],'IN');
$oAndGroup = $oOrGroup->andConditionGroup();
$aAndGroup->condition('type','banana')
  ->condition('field_ripe',1);
$oOrGroup->condition($oAndGroup);
$oQuery->condition($oOrGroup);
```

This doesn't work because `andConditionGroup()` isn't a method of `ConditionInterface`.

Is there a way to do this with `\Drupal::entityQuery()`, or do I have to revert to using `db_query()`?

Comment: Actually, there is a [`ConditionInterface::andConditionGroup()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21ConditionInterface.php/function/ConditionInterface%3A%3AandConditionGroup/8.2.x) method. Why do you think  `ConditionInterface` doesn't expose such method?

Comment: I see that the interface does expose this method, but when I use the above code, I get Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Condition::andConditionGroup() It looks like andConditionGroup() is not a method of the Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Condition class, but it is of the \Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Condition class. So I think I'm confused about how to properly create an entityQuery in the first place perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create both groups from the query, using the `condition()` method to plug the groups into the right places. Casting the query to a string will allow you to inspect the generated SQL to verify that it is what you would have created by hand (perhaps without some of the superfluous but harmless parentheses).

```php
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
$query = $storage->getQuery();
$bananas = $query->andConditionGroup()
  ->condition('type', 'banana')
  ->condition('field_ripe', 1);
$fruit = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->condition('type', ['apple', 'orange'], 'IN')
  ->condition($bananas);
$query->condition($fruit);
echo (string) $query . "\n";
```

I've reformatted the output to make it a bit more legible, but otherwise it's exactly as the API created it.

```sql
   SELECT "base_table"."vid" AS "vid", "base_table"."nid" AS "nid"
     FROM "node" "base_table"
LEFT JOIN "node_field_data" "node_field_data"
       ON "node_field_data"."nid" = "base_table"."nid"
LEFT JOIN "node_field_data" "node_field_data_2"
       ON "node_field_data_2"."nid" = "base_table"."nid"
LEFT JOIN "node__field_ripe" "node__field_ripe"
       ON "node__field_ripe"."entity_id" = "base_table"."nid"
    WHERE (
            "node_field_data"."type" IN ('apple', 'orange')
          )
       OR (
            ("node_field_data_2"."type" = 'banana')
            AND
            ("node__field_ripe"."field_ripe_value" = '1')
          )
```